# Threading.timer intervals random

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I'm eventually trying to have multiple threading.timer threads running with differing wait times but I am having trouble getting even one thread based on single variables to run correctly.

I've added lines to try and eliminate processing time drift but I'm still not getting predictable results. When I run this script:

```
import threading
import datetime
import time

def foo():
    print datetime.datetime.now()

print datetime.datetime.now()

iterations = 10

wait = 1

thread = None

next_call = time.time()

while iterations > 0:
    if thread == None or thread.is_alive() == False:
        next_call = next_call + wait
        thread = threading.Timer(next_call - time.time(), foo)
        thread.start()
        iterations -= 1
```

I get this output:

```
2015-08-04 16:46:17.606658
2015-08-04 16:46:18.656710
2015-08-04 16:46:19.607990
2015-08-04 16:46:20.654599
2015-08-04 16:46:21.626649
2015-08-04 16:46:22.753762
2015-08-04 16:46:23.610284
2015-08-04 16:46:24.729185
2015-08-04 16:46:25.609802
2015-08-04 16:46:26.608769
2015-08-04 16:46:27.610249
```

Which has a seemingly random pattern of uncertainty in the amount of time the timer functions wait. Is there some way I can be certain the function will wait for the correct time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try some other machines/configurations.

```
C:\bin\Python27\python.exe C:/www/wsgi/mysite/mysite/test.py
2015-08-04 20:24:36.491000
2015-08-04 20:24:37.492000
2015-08-04 20:24:38.491000
2015-08-04 20:24:39.491000
2015-08-04 20:24:40.491000
2015-08-04 20:24:41.491000
2015-08-04 20:24:42.491000
2015-08-04 20:24:43.491000
2015-08-04 20:24:44.491000
2015-08-04 20:24:45.491000
2015-08-04 20:24:46.491000

Process finished with exit code 0
```

That's Windows 7, PyCharm 4.5.1, python 2.7.9, all 64-bit

Comment: I'm pretty much bound to specifically using this set up, a Raspberry Pi with raspbian (Debian based linux) and the built in compiler with the unix console. It's some version of python 2.7, I can check more specifically tomorrow. Any insight into why this might be occurring?

Comment: @NickRothbacher: I can only speculate your machine/processor is being heavily loaded with some other program or service

Comment: Hmm, well running `top` indicates that there is no process using more than half a percent of cpu capacity and none using more than 1% of RAM. I'll keep looking but I guess I may have to be satisfied with the inaccuracy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for exactly a second of difference between each thread, this is what documentation has to say:

Quoting from [Python 3] (https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects)

> The interval the timer will wait before executing its action may not
>   be exactly the same as the interval specified by the user.